# Comparing several lmer models built on several similar datasets

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I did a study where I built a lmer model1 on data1. The dependent variable is continuous. There are 5 predictors (fixed effects), also continuous, and 2 random effects - factor and counts.

Now I obtained additional data (2 more courses) and was thinking to replicate the study. Of course some of the associations still hold, some are different, which probably depends on the context. However, let's say I fit model1 (lmer) on data1, model2 on data2, and model3 on data3. Estimates are as follows:

model1 on data1

```
    Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID        (Intercept) 1.6762   1.2947  
 wdeswc    (Intercept) 0.2536   0.5035  
 Residual              0.8643   0.9297  
Number of obs: 1754, groups:  ID, 1754; wdeswc, 410

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            1.37356    0.05339  334.90000  25.725  < 2e-16 ***
Narr                   0.28979    0.04572 1748.00000   6.338 2.95e-10 ***
Syn                    0.21517    0.04387 1744.50000   4.905 1.02e-06 ***
PCWC                  -0.12131    0.04441 1736.10000  -2.732  0.00636 ** 
Ref                   -0.26898    0.04432 1741.20000  -6.069 1.57e-09 ***
DeepC                 -0.10489    0.04186 1736.90000  -2.506  0.01231 *
```

model2 on data2

```
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID        (Intercept) 0.8828   0.9396  
 wdeswc    (Intercept) 0.9703   0.9850  
 Residual              0.8802   0.9382  
Number of obs: 649, groups:  ID, 649; wdeswc, 210

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           2.16892    0.09658 185.20000  22.457  < 2e-16 ***
Narr                  0.25577    0.07186 560.00000   3.559 0.000403 ***
Syn                   0.13732    0.07803 610.40000   1.760 0.078936 .  
PCWC                 -0.21327    0.06792 541.20000  -3.140 0.001781 ** 
Ref                  -0.15125    0.06523 619.60000  -2.319 0.020733 *  
DeepC                 0.13738    0.07048 632.70000   1.949 0.051701 .
```

model3 on data3

```
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID        (Intercept) 0.6639   0.8148  
 wdeswc    (Intercept) 0.9237   0.9611  
 Residual              0.7242   0.8510  
Number of obs: 736, groups:  ID, 736; wdeswc, 158

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           1.82404    0.09817 140.40000  18.580  < 2e-16 ***
Narr                  0.34032    0.05971 665.70000   5.699 1.81e-08 ***
Syn                   0.57655    0.07328 669.20000   7.868 1.47e-14 ***
PCWC                  0.09247    0.05706 648.20000   1.621   0.1056    
Ref                   0.03546    0.05356 650.10000   0.662   0.5082    
DeepC                -0.10841    0.06168 695.40000  -1.757   0.0793 .
```

While we could say that the first two models are "similar", the third one is "quite different" compared to the first one. However, to provide more context for the comparison, I calculated pseudo r squared, like this:

```
cor(predict(model1, newdata = data2, re.form=NA), 
    predict(model2, re.form=NA), 
    method="spearman", use="complete.obs")^2
```

and

```
cor(predict(model1, newdata = data3, re.form=NA), 
    predict(model3, re.form=NA), 
    method="spearman", use="complete.obs")^2
```

and the results are:

model1 vs. model2 = 0.7527592
model1 vs. model3 = 0.3574615

There are only two questions:

- does it make sense to compare models like this?
- can we conclude something from such a comparison?

Eventually, I would build a single model on all the data to get a general patterns. But, it's obvious that there are certain similarities and differences between those models that perhaps depend on the context of a particular course.

Comment: This comparison seems to tell you that model1 isn't particularly good at predicting dataset 3 (and probably vice versa), which makes sense since the coefficients for PCWS and Ref differ in signs. Do these variables have different ranges in the three datasets, by any chance? And: What exactly did you *want* to find out with this comparison?

Comment: Actually, those variables have (almost) the same ranges, everything seems to be fine there. Anyway, the general idea was to do a replication study. The original study was done using mixed-models and data1. I just wanted to build a similar model (slightly different random effects) on the new data, but that resulted in different signs and significance for some of the variables (like PCWC and Ref). So, I wanted to see where the difference is, and tried to compare those models. Honestly, not sure whether that is the best way to do a replication...

Comment: Are you sure that you want to compare the models and not the data sets? The models are clearly different, since the signs of the coefficients are. Do you really want to find out whether data set 3 significantly differs from 1 and 2? If so, you could analyze the collated data set including data set number as a co-predictor (including interactions between data set number and your predictors). -- However, if you find a significant interaction between data set number and one of your predictors (presumably PCWC and Ref), what would you conclude from that?

Comment: The original idea was quite simple - repeat the analysis on the new data, obtain the same/similar results, and show that all the patterns are the same. That didn't work, of course... I was also thinking to do what you suggested. Once I show that those models are sometimes different, sometimes similar, I will fit one model, including all the data, and check for the interaction. So, I guess there is no need to compare data/models?